# container initialization order in pod on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to run two containers on a single pod.

`container1` is a test that tries to connect to a SQL Server Database that runs on `container2`.

How can I make sure that the sql container (`container2`) will run and be ready before `container1` starts?

`initContainer` won't work here, as it will run before both containers.

This is my compose.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sql-test-pod
  labels:
    name: sql-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: my-sqldb
      image: docker-registry.com/database
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
        requests:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
    - name: tests
      tty: true
      stdin: true
      image: docker-registry.com/test
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
        requests:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
      env:
      - name: sqlhostname
        value: "SqlHostnamePlaceholder"
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
  tolerations:
  - key: "windows"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "2019"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Comment: You almost always want to run these two containers separately, and not in a plain Pod (the database in a StatefulSet, the application in a Deployment).  The application needs to handle the dependency itself, maybe restarting if the database isn't available.

Comment: I agree but in this specific case we do want the sql and tests to be on the same pod

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, No, But I'm trying a new way to use lifecycle postStart on sql container. I will update my conclusions on this post

Comment: @GalI. I wanted to offer a `postStart` but [read here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#discussion) - Kubernetes sends the postStart event immediately after the Container is created. There is no guarantee, however, that the postStart handler is called before the Container's entrypoint is called. So I'd go with `command` in this case.

Comment: @GalI. indeed what you found works, tested it (however didn't find this in kubernetes docs, will check). You can move it to [your own answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This may be helpful for other community members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make sure that `container1` will start only after `container2`'s SQL Server is up the only way I found is to use `postStart` container's lifecycle event.
`postStart` triggered after after the container is create, it is true that  there is no guarantee, that the postStart handler is called before the Container's entrypoint is called, **but it turns out that the Kubelet code that starts the container blocks the start of the next container until the post-start handler terminates.**

And this is how my new compose file will look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sql-test-pod
  labels:
    name: sql-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: my-sqldb
      image: docker-registry.com/database
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ['powershell.exe', '-command', "$connectionString = 'Server=sql-test-pod;User Id=user;Password=password'; $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString; $i=0; while($i -lt 6) {Try { $i++;$sqlConnection.Open();$sqlConnection.Close(); return}Catch {Write-Error $_; start-sleep 30}}"]
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
        requests:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
    - name: tests
      tty: true
      stdin: true
      image: docker-registry.com/test
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
        requests:
          memory: "4096Mi"
          cpu: "750m"
      env:
      - name: sqlhostname
        value: "sql-test-pod"
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
  tolerations:
  - key: "windows"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "2019"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Similar case you can find [here](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with current implements of `kubernetes`: all container in one pod will startup in same time(except the init container).

One solution is to enhance the code in `test container` to detect the state of `db container`, hold on until is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add [command and args to the container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod).

You can add `sleep` command if it's known approximate time for another container to start or add some logic within the command (`while` loop checking the connection, once it's connected, exit the loop and run main process - [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190513/shell-scripting-proper-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity)).

Note! Image's `entrypoint` will be replaced by this command:

> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file
> override the default command and arguments provided by the container
> image

For instance, for `nginx` and command container `spec` will look like (since `entrypoint` is replaced, it's necessary to provide a command to start the nginx server):

```
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      args: ["sleep 30 ; echo sleep ended ;  nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

More details here [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).